# comparing two object variables with == in javascript

Tags: javascript

as `==` in JavaScript is used for comparing two variables, but it ignores the datatype of variable,
gives true here,

```
"abc"=="abc"
true
```

gives false here,

```
new String("abc")==new String("abc")
false
```

but this still why output is coming as `false`, as value of both is same `abc` string object,
as javascript have new datatype of `Symbol`,

```
Symbol("abc")==Symbol("abc")
false
Symbol(new String("abc"))==Symbol(new String("abc"))
false
```

whats difference in both, what should be used in which scenarios, why both gives sameoutput?

Comment: in javascript, you'll find that even `({} !== {})` ... `whats difference in both`, they are not the same Object

Comment: Two different objects, regardless of their properties, are **never** `==` or `===` to each other.

Comment: It's unclear whether you're asking (a) why `new String("abc")==new String("abc")` is false, whether you're asking (b) why `Symbol("abc")==Symbol("abc")` is false, or both of those at the same time (or something on top of that?). Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: note: `Symbol.for('a') === Symbol.for('a')`